# How i can call the system popup menu from a TSynEdit component

Tags: delphi, synedit

When I make a right  click in a `TMemo`component the system display a  popup menu like this

[image]

but when I use a `TSynEdit` component this popup menu is not shown, the question is exist any way to activate this system popup menu in a TSynEdit component or do I have to implement myself a right-click popup menu for the TSynEdit component to get right-click Cut,Copy,Paste,Delete functionality ?

Comment: I have never used SynEdit (I have written my own editor control), but the general rule is that you cannot get the Windows standard menu in a custom editor control (without a lot of extra work).

Comment: (One would expect the SynEdit control to be shipped with its own popup menu... Isn't it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The popup menu you're showing is added by Windows itself to Edit controls (TMemo is a wrapper around a multiline Edit control). Since SynEdit isn't based on the Windows Edit control, but is implemented fully itself, Windows doesn't provide that menu.

If SynEdit doesn't provide a popup menu itself, you'll have to implement your own.